# Is there any way to shorten URL in SMS in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobile, journeybuilder, mobileconnect, sms

I am trying to schedule an SMS in the journey to the subscribers who did not open their email. I want to redirect the subscribers to their hosted email page.

I am using the below code to populate hosted email link in email.

```
%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(383,'Id',@Id))=%%
```

In the message, it's showing up.

> http://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/lurat1d1uu?qs=0adsffa7913f3b66e20e907542d34985a0314e14bda6c724a7fe5260c80158a814d04cc002dbbfdf1c5

How can I shorten this URL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a great question. We've tried using the [bit.ly shorten API method](https://dev.bitly.com/links.html#v3_shorten) in conjunction with an AMPscript HTTPGet function (to make a request to the API) to shorten a URL. This works well, but the problem was that we quickly hit a [rate limiting issue](https://dev.bitly.com/rate_limiting.html) where we started receiving a 403 HTTP Status codes back from bit.ly.

It turns out that bit.ly has a monthly rate limit of 5,000 links created and an hourly limit of 1,000 and a 100 in a minute. This is for the free usage edition. We looked into their paid plans and the cost was going to be pretty expensive (~$850 per month), so we ended up building our own API.

So, depending on how many SMS messages you want to send, the bit.ly API could be an option. If bit.ly is an option for you, here's some code that should work:

```
var @Id, @shortenUrl, @bitlyUrl, @link
set @Id = AttributeValue('Id')
set @link = URLEncode(CloudPagesURL(383,'Id',@Id))
set @bitlyUrl = 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&longUrl='
set @shortenUrl = HTTPGet(Concat(@bitlyUrl,@link,"&format=txt"))
```

Note that you obtain the `ACCESS_TOKEN` from your bit.ly account but it's persistent and doesn't expire, so you don't need to generate a new one each time.

Comment: Thanks for your help Eliot. Is there any other service we can use except bit.ly?

Comment: @Mohammed, you can use any service you want. I haven't done an extensive search, however it looks like [thelink.la](http://thelink.la/api-for-developer.php) does not have rate limiting. You can also install and host your own on a web server like [yourls.org](http://yourls.org/),

Comment: If I have answered your question, please accept it for the benefit of others.

Comment: No problem @Mohammed. If I have answered your question, please accept it (click on the tick icon).

Comment: Hi @EliotHarper - I have used this method to shorten a one click unsubscribe link included in my SMS message. I have noticed that the AMPScript on my page gets executed the moment bit.ly shortens the link. As a result all my contacts are getting automatically unsubscribed. Is there a way to prevent this from happening ?

Comment: Hi Vic, my guess is that bit.ly is making a GET request to the URL that you are shortening (to validate that the URL is valid), so this solution can't really be used with a one-click unsubscribe. You may want to explore other URL shortening services (refer to my earlier comment) and see if they make a GET request when the URL is shortened.

Comment: Hi @EliotHarper I use your mentioned code in SMS it's working fine but original URL contains + sings and these signs are converted into %20 which I click on bitly link which makes URL is not being recognized at server. Any solution here? Thanks.

Comment: @Sohail, the URLEncode function has [limited support for url encoding characters](https://ampscript.guide/URLEncode/). A simple solution would be to replace the converted characters, so for line 3 use `set @link = Replace(URLEncode(CloudPagesURL(383,'Id',@Id)), '%20', '+')`

Comment: @EliotHarper I tried with replace and it didn't work. I am still seeing + sign is being replaced with %20

Comment: OK, please can you provide the complete URL as that's not what I'm seeing.

Comment: @EliotHarper I actually have created another thread here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/315996/sms-signs-in-dynamic-url-using-bitly-api-in-ampscript 
My URL and code is also there. If you don't mind can you look at it and respond. Thanks.
I also notice that when we send URL, Bitly is actually replacing + with space and then generate shortURL which then send back to us. And when we click I think by default browser is adding %20 to whitespace.