# Shortening URL problem with ampscript (Bitly)

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, api, sms

I am trying to create a URL shortener API to SMS.

I follow the instructions of recommendations present in the question 161055 ([Is there any way to shorten URL in SMS in Marketing Cloud?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/161050/is-there-any-way-to-shorten-url-in-sms-in-marketing-cloud/161055)).

I am doing almost equal but i always receive and server error and the sms sending fails.

The code that i am using is this:

```
%%[
var  @shortenUrl, @bitlyUrl, @link
set @link = URLEncode('https://www.example.com')
set @bitlyUrl = 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&longUrl='
set @shortenUrl = HTTPGet(Concat(@bitlyUrl,@link,"&format=txt"))
]%%
%%=RedirectTo(@shortenUrl)=%%
```

Is it possible that this method is no longer available? Or am i doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Pedro Pereira

Answer (score 2):

The method still works. For SMS, you don't use the RedirectTo() - That's just for tracked links in emails. Simply output the shortened URL:

```
%%[
var  @shortenUrl, @bitlyUrl, @link
set @link = URLEncode('https://www.example.com')
set @bitlyUrl = 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token=replaced&longUrl='
set @shortenUrl = HTTPGet(Concat(@bitlyUrl,@link,"&format=txt"))
]%%
%%=TRIM(@shortenUrl)=%%
```

Comment: Hi Macca, thanks for the help but unfortunately it didn't work.
The same error message appear: "An internal server error has occurred". 
My Bitly account is the free version, can this be a problem?

Comment: Yes. That could be a problem, if you've spent all your credits and can't shorten any more URLs. I'd paste your code into an email and send-preview to retrieve what @shortenUrl contains, grab it and paste it into your browser to see what happens. Your code looks pretty good to me and very similar to what I have in a number of SMSs.

Comment: I still could not make a first successful call, so the credits limits is not the problem,
Do you know if could be some settings issue? I am a API user.

Comment: If you place your script in an email, output the @shortenUrl at the bottom of your script ("%%=v(@shortenUrl)=%%"), do a send preview and then place that URL in your browser's address bar, what response do you get from bit.ly?

Comment: When i try the send preview i receive this error message:
"An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a HTTPGet function call. See inner exception for details.
 ClientID: 10__
 SubscriberID: 7__
 URL: https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token=R___&longUrl=https://www.__.pt&format=txt
An exception occurred when attempting to retrieve content by a HttpGet call. URL: https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token=R___&longUrl=https://www.__.pt&format=txt
The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error."
What can be causing this?

Comment: Try getting rid of the actual HttpGet() line in your script and just output the value of shortenUrl and then paste that into your browser to see what the error might be. The line where shortenUrl is set should be changed to this "set @shortenUrl = Concat(@bitlyUrl,@link,"&format=txt")"

Comment: Hi Macca, i done that and received a access token failed, then i realized that i was copping the wrong token. Thanks a lot for the help! Without this last tip I do not know if I would get to the problem.

Comment: @Macca , any update on this in Oct. 2020? Is there an out-of-the-box bit.ly connector (or any other url shortener?) ;It seems to be only on Social Studio?