# Dynamic Link Bitly V4

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, sms

I need to send a link to a CloudPage through SMS with an query param (www.example.com?**id=XXXX**), which the CloudPage will use to get value from a Data Extension and pre-fill some data to Contacts and ask for others.

This param value is different for each contact and the actual URL is too big, so I want to use Bitly to short this link. I can use AMPScript to create a [dynamic link with Bitly](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/161050/is-there-any-way-to-shorten-url-in-sms-in-marketing-cloud?rq=1), but this example is using V3 API, since it's going to be deactivated, I'm making it in V4.

[image: V3 will be deactivated on March]

The problem now it's I need to make an request through Bit.ly API with an JSON in request body, inside SMS message.

```
%%[
  var @testID, @cloudpage, @link, @leadId, @bitlyPage, @contentType, @content,
      @bitlyToken, @additionalHeaderName, @additionalHeaderValue, @output, @respheader
  set @testID = 'XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX'
  set @bitlyToken = 'myToken'
  set @bitlyPage = 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/bitlinks'
  set @contentType = 'application/json'
  set @additionalHeaderName = 'Authorization'
  set @additionalHeaderValue = concat('Bearer ', @bitlyToken)


  set @cloudpage = CloudPagesURL(1591,'id',@testID)
  set @link = URLEncode(@cloudpage)

  set @content = Stringfy({"long_url": @link})
]%%

  %%=HTTPPost2(@bitlyPage, @contentType, @content, true, @output,
        @respheader, @additionalHeaderName, @additionalHeaderValue)=%%

  Output: %%=v(@output)=%%
  Header: %%=v(@respheader)=%%
```

When I try to run this in Preview and test, I get the following error:

> There is an error in your email. Please contact your customer service representative. Error 1: Script SET Statement Invalid
> An error occurred when attempting to resolve a script expression. See inner exception for detail. Script Expression: Stringfy MemberID: nnnnnnn JobID: 0 An unrecognized expression appears in a script block.

If I try without Stringfy, I get this error:

> Error 1: Script SET Statement Invalid
> An error occurred when attempting to resolve a script expression. See inner exception for detail.

How can I send this JSON data in body? or there is another way to make this Bitly link?

Answer (score 3):

*Stringify* isn't an AMPscript function.  You should be able to use [**concat**](https://ampscript.guide/concat) instead:

```
%%[

  var @testID, @cloudpage, @link, @leadId, @bitlyPage, @contentType, @content,
  @bitlyToken, @additionalHeaderName, @additionalHeaderValue, @output, @respheader

  set @testID = 'XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX'
  set @bitlyToken = 'myToken'
  set @bitlyPage = 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/bitlinks'
  set @contentType = 'application/json'
  set @additionalHeaderName = 'Authorization'
  set @additionalHeaderValue = concat('Bearer ', @bitlyToken)


  set @cloudpage = CloudPagesURL(1591,'id',@testID)
  set @link = URLEncode(@cloudpage)

  set @content = concat('{"long_url": ', @link, '}')

]%%

%%=HTTPPost2(@bitlyPage, @contentType, @content, true, @output, @respheader, @additionalHeaderName, @additionalHeaderValue)=%%

Output: %%=v(@output)=%%
Header: %%=v(@respheader)=%%
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Adam answer, I was able to send the request to Bitly v4 API, but I had other problem: The response was a JSON and I was unable to get the "Link" attribute and use it in the message through AMPScript.

I saw that Guide Template Language could help me [to read the JSON field](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/gtlDatasourceTagExamples.htm).

So was able to do all the work, generate the link, get it and wirte the message using the following code ([also here!](https://gist.github.com/leto96/991bb33494d96d5dd0ed39e7d90d3ac3)).

```
%%[
    var @message, @link, @param, @bitlyPage, @contentType, @content,
        @bitlyToken, @additionalHeaderName, @additionalHeaderValue, @request, @response
    set @bitlyToken = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    set @bitlyPage = 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/bitlinks'
    set @contentType = 'application/json'
    set @additionalHeaderName = 'Authorization'
    set @additionalHeaderValue = concat('Bearer ', @bitlyToken)

    set @param = AttributeValue('attribute')

    set @link = concat('https://yourlink.com.br/something?id=', @param)

    set @content = concat('{"long_url": "',@link,'"}')

    set @request = HTTPPost(@bitlyPage, @contentType, @content, @response, 
      @additionalHeaderName, @additionalHeaderValue)

    set @message = 'Hello, here is the link '
  ]%%%%=v(@message)=%%{{.datasource responsevar type=variable}}{{.data}}{ "target" : "@response" }{{/data}}{{link}}{{/datasource}}
```

Comment: Did you find that Bitly makes a call to each unique URL, as if a recipient has clicked on the link? That's a problem for me when using the link as a call to action.