# SMS +Signs in Dynamic URL using bitly API in Ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am using the below code in SMS. However somehow the "+" sign in URL is being converted into %20, which is not being recognized by website.

URL should look like this..

```
https://abc/apex/ValidateCase?token=JD8XB07if/zK/DcgU3ht3IC4BzRA1WGQFBF9A5R8/ATJyqV/1ma3D+Bho+
```

But when I click on Bitly Link the final URL look like this

```
https://abc/apex/ValidateCase?token=JD8XB07if/zK/DcgU3ht3IC4BzRA1WGQFBF9A5R8/ATJyqV/1ma3D%20Bho%20
```

Here is the code

```
%%[ 
var @shortenUrl, @bitlyUrl, @link 
set @link = URLEncode(case_link_custom) 
set @bitlyUrl = 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token=abcd&longUrl=' 
set @shortenUrl = HTTPGet(Concat(@bitlyUrl,@link,"&format=txt")) 
]%% 
Please click %%=TRIM(@shortenUrl)=%%. Msg&Data Rates May Apply. 4msg/month.
```

I also tried removing the URLEncode but still the same issue. I did one more test rather using API i just manually pick the url and converted and that works. So seems like it's not Bitly but some of function in Ampscript.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Any suggestion... Anyone ????

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hacky, but if you know you have no actual spaces in your case urls, why not just replace '%20' with a URLEncoded plus symbol ("%2B")?

```
%%[ 
var @shortenUrl, @bitlyUrl, @link

/* Replace %20 in URLEncoded string with %2B */
set @link = Replace(URLEncode(case_link_custom,1,1)'%20','%2B')
set @bitlyUrl = 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token=abcd&longUrl=' 
set @shortenUrl = HTTPGet(Concat(@bitlyUrl,@link,"&format=txt")) 
]%%Please click %%=TRIM(@shortenUrl)=%%. Msg&Data Rates May Apply. 4msg/month.
```

If you do have spaces in your URLs, drop using the URLEncode function and just manually replace all the illegal characters in your URL with their URLEncoded counterparts using the [Replace()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Replace.htm) function, commonly (:/.:,?=&#+).

Comment: No this one also didn't work.The final link is still have %20

Comment: The issue was actually with the URLEncode function. It accepts another couple of params to correctly URL encode. That's why the replace function couldn't find any %20... The url hadn't been encoded. I've updated the answer adding the two supplementary URLEncode params

Answer (score 0):

Ok i made it work by

```
set @link = Replace(URLEncode(case_link_custom),'+','%2B')
```

Thanks @Macca.