# Shortening URLs in the SMS being sent from Service Cloud

Tags: apex, marketing-cloud, api, servicecloud, sms

We are sending SMS messages from Service cloud using Transactional API(Marketing Cloud).We were planning to send attachments but transactional API does not support attachments hence we have decided to include attachment links in the SMSes. But the links for those attachments are quite big.How can we personalize/shorten the url. My plan is to send a small url in the SMS and when the user clicks,he must be redirected to the original attachment url. How can this be implemented and Is it even feasible?Please share your expertise and options you see to implement this use case.
Just to inform all the templates are already configured in Service Cloud and we cannot redo the wheel to configuring the templates in marketing cloud with AMPScript.

Comment: It depends on many things, are your links static? Or do you need to personalize them? How many are you planning to shorten per minute/hour/month? Check out Eliot's answer here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/161050/is-there-any-way-to-shorten-url-in-sms-in-marketing-cloud

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to shorten URL in SMS in Marketing Cloud?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/161050/is-there-any-way-to-shorten-url-in-sms-in-marketing-cloud)

Comment: No It does not, since as i said i am not using marketing cloud templates where i can use the AMPscript.

Comment: Sure. But you're sending content through Marketing Cloud, so you can embed the AMPScript in that content and the AMPScript will execute.

Comment: Thanks Macca, when i include ampscript in the html content,they are rendering as literal strings.